# Three Fiber get current viewport (taking account for zoom)

Tags: three.js, react-three-fiber

in Three Fiber you can use `useThree()` to get the dimensions (in three units) like this:

```js
    const { viewport, camera } = useThree();
    //(target coordinates as second parameter)
    const dimensions = viewport.getCurrentViewport(camera, [0, 13, 0])
```

If I change the zoom on the camera, the effective width is much less, but getCurrentViewport reports the width at `zoom === 1`

How can I get the visible width taking zoom into account?